# Why does the mean term have a higher effect than the covariance term in MV optimization?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio, mean-variance, markowitz

I am trying to use the mean-variance (MV) optimization framework. When I change the mean term using future-ground-truth return (I am not supposed to do so), it has a higher effect on the MV optimization than using the future-ground-truth covariance matrix.

Why does the mean term have a higher effect than the covariance term?

Comment: Could you please add more details?